# Add historic cyrillic letters as Unicode to latex in Overleaf

Tags: unicode

I have tried to add the unicode symbol for the russian "[yat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yat)" symbol in my document and used [this website](https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html) to find out it's unicode,  yet I have trouble adding it to the code.

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0462}
\cyrchar\CYRYAT
```

Am I missing a package in overleaf? Is this character even possible to be written in latex?

**Edit:** Guess I found an alternative:
In the userpackage add:

```
\usepackage{tipa}
```

and then I used http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html suggested by [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_file_encodings_and_line_endings_should_I_use%3F) and drew my character in it.

I then added

```
\textcrb
```

Where I needed it in my document.

If anyone has a better solution, thanks a lot

**Edit:** in the menu you can change the compiler too and then use XeLaTex

Answer (score 5):

You can use the glyph from the X2 encoding and tell LaTeX that it's the default encoding for it. Don't expect hyphenation to work well with words containing the character.

The `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` declarations are not needed, I added them just for complete information.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T2A]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with TeX Live 2018 or later

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRYAT}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyryat}{X2}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0462}{\CYRYAT}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0463}{\cyryat}

\begin{document}

ѣсть лѣчу

\end{document}
```

[image]

X2 also supports Big Yus and Izhitsa, but not other historic characters.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T2A]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with TeX Live 2018 or later

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRYAT}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyryat}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRBYUS}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrbyus}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRIZH}{X2}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrizh}{X2}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0462}{\CYRYAT}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0463}{\cyryat}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{046A}{\CYRBYUS}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{046B}{\cyrbyus}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0474}{\CYRIZH}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0475}{\cyrizh}

\begin{document}

ѣсть лѣчу ѢѪѴ ѣѫѵ

\end{document}
```

[image: more glyphs]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to define unicode representations by hand, you can also use the `X2` glyph container as parameter to `fontenc` package. See [section 2.5](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf) of the latex font encoding guide.

```latex
\usepackage[X2, T1]{fontenc}
```

It includes these ancient cyrillic characters you are interested in.

It works then simply via the `\cyr` macro, e.g.

```latex
{\cyr \CYRYAT}  % for the capital 'yat'.
```

See on the left the latex code and on the right the representation in the document in the image below:

[image]

For reproduction:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[X2, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,german]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}

    \texttt{\{$\backslash$cyr $\backslash$CYRYAT\}} & {\cyr \CYRYAT} \\
    \texttt{\{$\backslash$cyr $\backslash$cyryat\}} & {\cyr \cyryat} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```